# Access a location with just the Project Key in Google Speech to Text API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm working on a project where I'm using the Google's Speech to Text API.

I want to assign a boost value to some of the words of my choice

I'm using the SpeechAdaption for this.

But the problem here is that I just have the secret key associated with the project. I don't have the project_id

I'm able to create a client using this key

While creating a custom class using adaptation client I'm being asked to specify the parent resource where the custom class and phrase set id will be created as shown below

```
# The parent resource where the custom class and phrase set will be created.
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Create the custom class resource
    adaptation_client.create_custom_class(
        {
            "parent": parent,
            "custom_class_id": custom_class_id,
            "custom_class": {
                "items": [
                    {"value": "barrows"}
                ]
            },
        }
    )
```

I want to know how can I get a valid location corresponding to the project using the project key instead of project id

Any help on this will be great

Thank you in advance!!

I read the documentation. It's mentioned over there to create the credentials. However I don't have access to do any of that. All I have is the secret key associated with the project

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the secret key you are using? How have you created it?

Comment: For my project, a service account is created and I have generated the key using the steps shown in this link https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortianalyzer/6.2.0/cookbook/9036/creating-a-google-service-account-key